# Django + raw SQL query - how to juggle between a null value for a field in sql query

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a sql query. It first gets all the songs from the playlists. These songs could have an entry in Block Song Table and possibly some songs may not have an entry in the block song model.

So, for those songs who have an entry they will have an unblock_flag which is a boolean field and will carry either true or false. But, the concern is that those songs which will not have an entry in the block song model table will have null values for unblock_flag. I also thought to use an update in it but that also didn't work. The field to be changed is `core_blocksong.unblock_flag` in the below query.

So, if anyone can suggest any other ways to make this scenario work?

```
select songs.id, songs.name, songs.artist, songs.album, songs.albumart, 
songs."albumartThumbnail", cpr.votes, is_requested, core_blocksong.unblock_flag from (select id, 
name, artist, album, albumart, "albumartThumbnail" from (select song_id from 
core_plsongassociation where 
playlist_id in (1477)) as sinpl left join songs on sinpl.song_id=id) as 
songs left join (select` song_id, votes, bool_or(user_id=null) as is_requested from
(select * from core_priorityrequests where client_id=2876 and is_played=False) as clpr left 
join core_priorityrequests_requested_by
on clpr.id=priorityrequests_id group by priorityrequests_id, song_id, votes) as cpr 
on songs.id=cpr.song_id left join core_blocksong on songs.id = core_blocksong.song_id where core_blocksong.unblock_flag='f'and core_blocksong.client_id=2876;`
```

Adding the Block Song Model Table:

```
class BlockSong(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client')
    playlist = models.ForeignKey('Playlist', blank=True, null=True)
    song = models.ForeignKey('Song')
    unblock_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Update 1:**

I have found the answer but here, I am getting a small error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 3: ...select core_blocksong.song_id from core_blocksong on (songs....
```

And the Query:

```
select songs.id, songs.name, songs.artist, songs.album, songs.albumart,
songs."albumartThumbnail", cpr.votes from (select id, name, artist, album, albumart, "albumartThumbnail" from (select song_id from core_plsongassociation where playlist_id in (1477)) as sinpl left join songs 
on sinpl.song_id=id where explicit=False) as songs left join (select song_id, votes, bool_or(thirdpartyuser_id=177) as is_requested from (select * 
from core_priorityrequests where client_id=2876 and is_played=False) as clpr left join core_priorityrequests_third_party_user on clpr.id=priorityrequests_id group by priorityrequests_id, song_id, votes) as cpr on songs.id=cpr.song_id where songs.id not in (select core_blocksong.song_id from core_blocksong on (songs.id = core_blocksong.song_id) where core_blocksong.unblock_flag = 'f' and core_blocksong.client_id=2876);
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong in on here in the second last line?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing this with Django's ORM?

Comment: We have to use the already existing code only @andyw.

Comment: If you could suggest something better, I can look forward for it as well.